# javascript: remove slash "extension" from string?

Tags: javascript, string

What's the **fastest method**, to remove a specific extension from a String **by not using regexp** (.html, .htm, .xml or whatever you feed it with) ?

I need this to convert ~500 strings <1s at once.

example:

```
var myURL  = 'home/johndoe/likes/pepsico.html' 
var result = 'home/johndoe/likes/pepsico'
```

**EDIT :**

```
      var alias = window.location.pathname //'/home/johndoe/likes/pepsico.html' 

      alias = alias.substr(alias.indexOf('/') + 1)
      alias = alias.substr( 0, alias.lastIndexOf('.') );
```

how can i optimize this ?

Comment: Are regular expressions too slow? How long does your solution take so far? Have you had a look at string functions? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Comment: somebodfy told me, that regexp is a slow way and i should not use it ? O_o

Comment: Yes, regular expressions are slow compared to other string functions, but they might still be fast enough for your job. Implement something, profile it and *then*, if it is too slow, search for a faster solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't even need a regular expression to do the job:

```
var myURL  = 'home/johndoe/likes/pepsico.html',
    myURL  = myURL.substr( 0, myURL.lastIndexOf('.') );

console.log( myURL );  // "home/johndoe/likes/pepsico"
```

Comment: thank you (all) - this is my result (see above) - how can i optimize this ?

Answer (score 2):

Make use of : [JavaScript lastIndexOf() Method](http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/javascript-lastindexof-method.shtml) with [JavaScript substring() Method](http://freewebdesigntutorials.com/javaScriptTutorials/jsStringObject/substringMethod.htm)

```
var myURL  = 'home/johndoe/likes/pepsico.html',
myURL  = myURL.substring(0, myURL.lastIndexOf('.'));
alert(myURL);
```

Comment: The answer would be perfect if those links would refer `MDC` instead of `w3fools`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var myURL  = 'home/johndoe/likes/pepsico.html';
var result = myURL.substr(0, myURL.lastIndexOf("."));
// .substring() also works
```

Note: the above examples do not check if there is no `.` in the string.